# How to join two tables based on two conditions and sum a column?

Tags: sql, pyspark

I am doing some sql-like queries on `pyspark`. I have two tables `table` and `table1`

```
table.show()

+--------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+----------+-----+
|          identifier|identifier_type|          timestamp|device_lat|device_lon|count|
+--------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+----------+-----+
|ccf7758a-155f-4eb   |           gaee|2020-03-17 13:00:00| 40.764214| -73.98244|   19|
|ccf7758a-155f-4eb   |           gaee|2020-03-17 14:00:00| 40.761467| -73.98039|   14|
|ccf7758a-155f-4eb   |           gaee|2020-03-17 00:00:00| 40.760067| -73.97952|   12|
|ccf7758a-155f-4eb   |           gaee|2020-03-17 15:00:00| 40.759586| -73.98214|    9|
|2f4bd30c-0a59-4da   |           gaee|2020-03-18 23:00:00| 42.693657| -73.80621|    7|
|2f4bd30c-0a59-4da   |           idxx|2020-03-17 19:00:00| 40.768757|-73.621605|    7|
```

and

```
table1.show()

+--------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+----------+-----+
|          identifier|identifier_type|          timestamp|device_lat|device_lon|count|
+--------------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+----------+-----+
|ccf7758a-155f-4eb   |           gaee|2020-03-17 13:00:00| 40.764214| -73.98244|   15|
|ccf7758a-155f-4eb   |           gaee|2020-03-17 14:00:00| 40.761467| -73.98039|   17|
|ccf7758a-155f-4eb   |           gaee|2020-03-17 00:00:00| 40.760067| -73.97952|   13|
|ccf7758a-155f-4eb   |           gaee|2020-03-19 15:00:00| 40.759586| -73.98214|    9|
|2f4bd30c-0a59-4da   |           gaee|2020-03-18 23:00:00| 42.693657| -73.80621|    7|
|2f4bd30c-0a59-4da   |           idxx|2020-03-17 16:00:00| 40.768757|-73.621605|    7|
```

I would like to make a join of the two tables and make a sum on count if the same identifier appear at the same timestamp and have something like

```
table1.show()

+--------------------+---------------+-------------------+-----+
|          identifier|identifier_type|          timestamp|count|
+--------------------+---------------+-------------------+-----+
|ccf7758a-155f-4eb   |           gaee|2020-03-17 13:00:00|   34|
|ccf7758a-155f-4eb   |           gaee|2020-03-17 14:00:00|   31|
|ccf7758a-155f-4eb   |           gaee|2020-03-17 00:00:00|   25|
|ccf7758a-155f-4eb   |           gaee|2020-03-17 15:00:00|    9|
|ccf7758a-155f-4eb   |           gaee|2020-03-19 15:00:00|    9|
|2f4bd30c-0a59-4da   |           idxx|2020-03-18 23:00:00|   14|
|2f4bd30c-0a59-4da   |           idxx|2020-03-17 16:00:00|    7|
|2f4bd30c-0a59-4da   |           idxx|2020-03-17 19:00:00|    7|
```

Comment: In SQL you'd `UNION ALL` the two tables and aggregate then with `GROUP BY identifier, identifier_type, timestamp` calculating `SUM(count)`. Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tables have exactly the same columns, then it's easier to `UNION ALL` them first

```
SELECT identifier, identifier_type, timestamp, SUM(count) as count
FROM (
  SELECT identifier, identifier_type, timestamp, count
  FROM table 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT identifier, identifier_type, timestamp, count
  FROM table1
)
GROUP BY identifier, identifier_type, timestamp
```

EDIT: Actually "the same" columns aren't required, but they should have columns `identifier, identifier_type, timestamp, count` compatible by data types

Comment: thanks. Can I add the condition `where timestamp >= 2020-03-19`. I would like just the data after `2020-03-19`

Comment: Sure, do it just before `GROUP BY` line